# Array size issue when copying GoogleSheet to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get a sheet of data as an array, perform some processing, then save it to another sheet.

Without attempting any intermediate processing,

```
var booking = getRowsData(sheet);  //should create the array

var range = target.getRange(lastDBRow+1,1,numRows); //obtains the destination range (numRows logged as 3)
```

then

```
range.setValues([booking]); //tries to save the values but throws an error "Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 3"
```

Checking the booking object with

```
var response = ui.prompt(booking.length + "  " + booking[0].length, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
```

shows length 3 and 
booking[0].length  (which I understood to be the columns) as undefined....

So why the row length mismatch?
And should the columns value be undefined?

My thanks in advance!

The full code is :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('New booking');
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var numRows= lastRow-1

var target = ss.getSheetByName('Test');  //temp redirect to test sheet
var lastDBRow =target.getLastRow();      //we want to append the data after this


var booking = getRowsData(sheet);        // Get data to copy as array object
= ui.prompt(booking.length + "  " + booking[0].length, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
//                                       Returns 3  Undefined

var response = ui.prompt(numRows, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
//                                         Returns 3

var range = target.getRange(lastDBRow+1,1,numRows);   //  Must match range size
range.setValues([booking]);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide about the detail information of ``getRowsData()``?

Comment: getRowsData is getting data from a sheet which is 4 rows (including header with entry in every column) and about 30 columns, but not all cells are populated.  Cell contents are  a mix of strings values, dates, Boolean  and formulae.  Does that help?  Thanks for looking at this...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that showing the script will help to think of about your issue. So can you provide the script of ``getRowsData()``? And then, is this current script your latest script? If it's not latest one, can you also update it?

Comment: `sheet.getDataRange().getValues()` gets all of the data in a sheet in a 2D Array. [Read About It Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: I have this problem sometimes. Normally use the debug mode to understand the data I'm inputting. Often the solution is as simple as to either add or remove a pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there is no column count defined in this range:
var range = target.getRange(lastDBRow+1,1,numRows);   //  Must match range size
range.setValues([booking]);
Without being about to use debug, I can't confirm my idea, but I see you are defining the starting row, the starting column and the number of rows, but not the number of columns.  I don't know for sure if that error message would be caused by that, but it looks like something to consider.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, I agree it should be different to get the column count right.  I tried changing it to var range = target.getRange(lastDBRow+1,1,numRows,sheet.getLastColumn() );  but I still get the same error message which says " Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 3"  .  Currently mystified!

Comment: Problem solved.  My error was in creating the object using range.getRowsData() which clearly generates a different format which would not return to the sheet with range.setValues().  I am now using range.getValues and achieving the desired result.  Many thanks to anyone who has been looking at this.